# Array as class member and refcounting

Tags: php, php-internals

There is something that confuses me. Let there be a class member 
`Foo::$bar`, which has to be initialized as an empty array in the 
constructor. If I do that (via `zend_update_property`), its refcount is 
increased (from 1, which it gets after alloc + `array_init`, to 2). It is 
obvious why this happens, since from `zend_update_property`'s perspective, it gets a 
variable from somone in the outside world, and so it is right to ++ it.

But in this particular case, the array being initialized in the 
constructor, it does not need a refcount of 2, 1 is right, since it's 
used only by the object (yet).

So I thought I will `Z_DELREF_P()` it. And it worked. Until I started 
valgrind, which was reporting:

```
==4538== Invalid read of size 4
==4538==    at 0x822D3C6: _zval_ptr_dtor (zend.h:385)
==4538==    by 0x823C1FF: _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper (zend_variables.c:189)
==4538==    by 0x824E1A1: zend_hash_destroy (zend_hash.c:529)
==4538==    by 0x826655A: zend_object_std_dtor (zend_objects.c:45)
==4538==    by 0x8266A28: zend_objects_free_object_storage 
(zend_objects.c:126)
==4538==    by 0x826C43D: zend_objects_store_del_ref_by_handle_ex 
(zend_objects_API.c:220)
==4538==    by 0x826C0AC: zend_objects_store_del_ref 
(zend_objects_API.c:172)
==4538==    by 0x823BD77: _zval_dtor_func (zend_variables.c:52)
==4538==    by 0x822B99B: _zval_dtor (zend_variables.h:35)
==4538==    by 0x822D463: _zval_ptr_dtor (zend_execute_API.c:443)
==4538==    by 0x823C1FF: _zval_ptr_dtor_wrapper (zend_variables.c:189)
==4538==    by 0x824E518: zend_hash_apply_deleter (zend_hash.c:614)
==4538==  Address 0x44c1718 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 20 free'd
```

which happens when the engine destroys the object (when the object runs out of scope - the destructor is also called).

So it looks like the ZE really needs the refcount to be 2. All other 
tests I've written work fine, no memleaks, no segfaults whatsoever.

Still I am a little bit confused: **WHY** does it need it be higher than 
(from my understanding) it should be?

Comment: Have you thought about that one refcount will be decreased if the constructors scope ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hakre's question made me think.

The explanation is the following: when the ZE destroys the object, it also destroys (`zval_ptr_dtor`) each property of the object. So it is right to have a refcount of 1 after the destructor was called, which is what I have currently, since I also call `zval_ptr_dtor` on that specific property decreasing its refcount from 2 to 1.

The ZE will take care of the rest.